# How do I run a command in background using commands module in python?

Tags: python, background-process

I want to run a system command in the background using python 2.7, this is what I have:

```
import commands
path = '/fioverify.fio'

cmd= "/usr/local/bin/fio" + path + " "+ " &"
print cmd
handle = commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)
```

This fails.  If I remove the ampersand `&` it works. I need to run a command (`/usr/local/bin/fio/fioverifypath`) in the background.

Any pointers on how to accomplish this?

Comment: What does *'running in the background'* mean in this context? Continuing after your script finishes? Running alongside the script?

Comment: It's also worth noting that [``commands``](http://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html) is deprecated in favour of [``subprocess``](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess).

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `commands`; it's deprecated and not actually useful for your purposes. Use `subprocess` instead.

```
fio = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/local/bin/fio", path])
```

runs the `fio` command in parallel with your process and binds the variable `fio` to a handle to the process. You can then call `fio.wait()` to wait for the process to finish and retrieve its return status.

Comment: Code snip I was looking for. What you put above works so no need of code snip now. I replied accordingly later.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module, [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) allows you to run a command as a subprocess (in the background) and check its status.

Comment: My requirement is: I want my script to not to wait till fio execution completes. Script should proceed while FIO is running in the background. I also want to fetch the pid for the fio forked.

Comment: Thanks. Got it. handle = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/local/bin/fio", path]) runs it in background.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [sh.py](http://amoffat.github.com/sh/), it has support for background commands:

```
import sh

bin = sh.Command("/usr/local/bin/fio/fioverify.fio")
handle = bin(_bg=True)
# ... do other code ...
handle.wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

### Running processes in the background using Python 2.7

`commands.getstatusoutput(...)` isn't smart enough to handle background processes, use `subprocess.Popen` or `os.system`.

**Reproducing the error of how `commands.getstatusoutput` fails on background processes:**

```
import commands
import subprocess

#This sleeps for 2 seconds, then stops, 
#commands.getstatus output handles sleep 2 in foreground okay
print(commands.getstatusoutput("sleep 2"))

#This sleeps for 2 seconds in background, this fails with error:
#sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
print(commands.getstatusoutput("sleep 2 &"))
```

**A demo of how subprocess.Popen succeeds on background processes:**

```
#subprocess handles the sleep 2 in foreground okay:
proc = subprocess.Popen(["sleep", "2"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = proc.communicate()[0]
print(output)

#alternate way subprocess handles the sleep 2 in foreground perfectly fine:
proc = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/sh', '-c', 'sleep 2'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = proc.communicate()[0]
print("we hung for 2 seconds in foreground, now we are done")
print(output)


#And subprocess handles the sleep 2 in background as well:
proc = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/sh', '-c', 'sleep 2'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print("Broke out of the sleep 2, sleep 2 is in background now")
print("twiddling our thumbs while we wait.\n")
proc.wait()
print("Okay now sleep is done, resume shenanigans")
output = proc.communicate()[0]
print(output)
```

**A demo of how os.system can handle background processes:**

```
import os
#sleep 2 in the foreground with os.system works as expected
os.system("sleep 2")

import os
#sleep 2 in the background with os.system works as expected
os.system("sleep 2 &")
print("breaks out immediately, sleep 2 continuing on in background")
```